# Using std::result_of<> for member method of member type

Tags: c++, templates, typename, result-of

I am working with a HashMap type that does not specify its KeyType as a public member, only the ValueType. A way to retrieve the KeyType would be to use `std::result_of` with the `HashMap<>::Entry::GetKey()` method. I can't get it to work in a template though.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Map {
public:
  using ValueType = V;
  class Entry {
  public:
    K GetKey();
  };
};
```

This works fine:

```
using M = Map<int, float>;
using T = std::result_of<decltype(&M::Entry::GetKey)(M::Entry)>::type;
static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "T is not int");
```

But how would I do it from a template where `M` is a template type parameter? I have tried to use the above and insert `typename` keywords with no success.

```
template <typename M>
struct GetKeyType {
  using T = std::result_of<decltype(&(typename M::Entry)::GetKey)(typename M::Entry)>::type;    
};

using T = GetKeyType<Map<int, float>>::T;
static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "T is not R");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&M::Entry::GetKey` is a whole, you should not separate them by a `typename`.

The following code will work:

```
template <typename M>
struct GetKeyType {
  using T = typename std::result_of<decltype(&M::Entry::GetKey)(typename M::Entry)>::type;
};
```

Comment: That must be the only version I haven't tried. :^) Why does it accept `&M::Entry::GetKey` as is? Isn't `M::Entry` a dependent type that needs to be accessed via `typename`?

Comment: @NiklasR The name being lookup-ed is `GetKey`, `typename` disambiguator is only used when the name actually being lookup-ed is a type, which is not the case here. `M::Entry::GetKey` is a qualified name, which is a whole, you can't simply split it into pieces.